# Passing parameter from Context Consumer results in "TypeError": ... is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am using a Provider to interact with DB and store values, which are passed to Consumer components:

```
this.state = {
            ...
            abilities: {
                "bra": 0,
                "agi": 0,
                "int": 0,
                "cun": 0,
                "will": 0,
                "pre": 0
            },
```

A consumer does display the values and now I need to provide a way to change the values back in the provider. I have done that before with passing the function through a contextType. Now I also need to identify which value of the object should be changed and I am stuck with passing a value which would enable me to do so. I have written this function in the Provider:

```
raiseAbility = ability => {
        console.log(ability)
        this.setState((state) => ({
            abilities: {...state.abilities, ability: ability + 1}
        }))
    }
```

When I try to pass a parameter (a key of the object in Provider's state) React tells me that the function is not a funtion:

```
<Button ... onClick={this.context.raiseAbility("bra")}>+</Button>
...
TypeError: _this2.context.raiseAbility is not a function
```

What is in this case the best way to pass back the parameter?

Comment: When you use the form `this.context` React will find the closest Provider above and use its value. Are you sure the closest Provider to this component is the one that has the `raiseAbility` method?

Comment: Yes it is - there is only one Provider in my project.  However I have defined the context in the component (static contextType = CharacterContext;) and it solved the problem. So the problem was that React could not find the function?

Comment: Yes, you have to declare the `contextType` so that React is able to find it. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype).